# Converting foreach to linq for better runtime

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a bit of difficulties trying convert my foreach to a database query. was wondering if I can receive some assistance.

Each Interaction can be tied to attendees, attendees can either be people or businesses. We'll just say they can only be tied to businesses for a simple example.

My query needs to include interactions where the business has no other activity before the reporting start date to fiscal start date.

For example if the current Fiscal year end for the client is April 1 2015 to March 31 2015

> John Smith had a meeting  June 1st 2015, and another meeting October 15 2015,
>
> If I query a report between April to August, John will appear in the report.
>
> If I query a report for the month of October, John will not show up.

Current working but very poor performance code

```
BusinessImpactIndepth = new BindableCollection<IndepthInfo>();
           
var query =  unitOfWork.InteractionRepository.Get(
                _Interaction =>
                    _Interaction.ActivityDate <= EndDate && _Interaction.ActivityDate >= StartDate &&
                    _Interaction.Active && _Interaction.Indepth == true && _Interaction.Program.Reportable ,
                    includeProperties:
                        new[]
                        {
                            "Attendees", "Attendees.Business", "Attendees.Person"
                        });
foreach (var interaction in query)
{
    foreach (var interactionAttendee in interaction.Attendees)
    {
        if (interactionAttendee.Business != null)
        {
            var businessInteractions =
                unitOfWork.InteractionRepository.Get(
                    i =>
                        i.ActivityDate <= StartDate && i.ActivityDate >= FiscalStartDate &&
                        i.Attendees.Any(x => x.Business.Id == interactionAttendee.Business.Id));
            if (!businessInteractions.Any())
            {                    
                var interactionItem = new IndepthInfo
                {
                    Id = interaction.Id,
                    Date = interaction.ActivityDate.ToShortDateString(),
                    Description = interaction.Impact.ToString(),
                    Client = interactionAttendee.Business.Name,
                 };

            if (!BusinessImpactIndepth.Any(x => x.Id == interactionItem.Id))
                BusinessImpactIndepth.Add(interactionItem);

            }
        }                        
    }
}
```

What I tried but the query crashes.

```
var query = unitOfWork.InteractionRepository.Get(
                _Interaction =>
                    _Interaction.ActivityDate <= EndDate && _Interaction.ActivityDate >= StartDate &&
                    _Interaction.Active && _Interaction.Indepth == true && _Interaction.Program.Reportable &&
                    (_Interaction.Attendees.Any(
                        attendee =>
                            (attendee.Business != null &&
                             attendee.Business.Interactions.Any(
                                 i =>
                                     i.ActivityDate <= StartDate && i.ActivityDate >= FiscalStartDate &&
                                         i.Attendees.Any(x => x.Business.Id == attendee.Business.Id))))),
                    includeProperties: new[] { "Attendees", "Attendees.Business", "Attendees.Person" });
```

Cause of why query is crashing - Business.Interactions is of type IEnumerable and that's not linq friendly.

Comment: You really want better performance? Don't use LINQ or foreach at all. Write a stored procedure, View, or something else on the db.

Comment: You should profile the query to identify the performance problems first

Comment: I would upvote @eric-hotinger s comment 1000 times if I could. Don't use Linq. Create a stored procedure and return just the rows you need using a SELECT query with JOINs

Comment: @OguzOzgul: LINQ will create a SELECT query with JOINs if you use it appropriately. Why would you expect a stored procedure to be faster? It's not like all the data is being pulled back to the client and filtered there (if you do it properly).

Comment: If you even be able to convert this to linq you will not understand what you have wrote after several days! you probably forget it and every one else must put much more effort to understand your code. consider writing readable and understandable code. Linq is not always readable.

Comment: @jon-skeet "If you do it properly" is the key here. I am standing for my comment as being a poor guy who spent nights analyzing hang dumps for our customers' on-line banking systems to find out someone had not done it properly.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: But that's like me saying "Don't use a relational database - it's horribly insecure" just because I've seen lots of people introduce SQL injection attacks instead of using parameterized SQL. Surely explaining the right way to use a tool is better than telling them to avoid the tool altogether. Can you think of *any* tool you've seen that hasn't been abused?

Comment: This is all predicated on how the stack is organized. Linq for sql/entities will produce the correct SQL and will be performant. Linq to objects with the data already loaded and filtering through a huge dataset will cause slowdowns. We need to know how your application is set up in order to provide good suggestions.

Comment: I agree with @EricHotinger. Write a stored procedure. Also, add an index to the date columns.

Comment: Personally, I find these "don't use LINQ" comments rather disturbing and the antithesis of how we should be helping people. Back these comments up with facts rather than perpetuating hearsay, because, frankly, they're rather half baked. I'd consider moving to stored procedures as an extreme measures to take only after extensive measurement.

Comment: @jon-skeet No.You can even abuse sysinternals' process monitor to let it eat up all the memory of the server by just not closing it. What I am actually against is, we are being pushed to higher layers of programming concepts all the time, intentionally, so today people we call software developers have no idea of what actually happens when they issue a statement (linq is just an example. What about await? Parallel? Do they really know what asynchronous programming means and it's effect on cpu cycles?), most of the time causing trouble when it comes to solutions with millions of end users.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: So your answer is to say "Don't use LINQ! Don't use async/await!" Maybe don't use C# at all? Is assembly okay? Again, I would rather teach people how to understand and use things properly than simply warn against them entirely, unless they *really* provide no value. (I believe that both LINQ and async/await provide huge amounts of value.)

Comment: @spender You are right. I think VS could help by having a Linq Execution Plan Analyzer in that sense.

Comment: @Master : can you confirm that `unitOfWork.InteractionRepository.Get` returns `IQueryable<Interaction>` (or whatever the generic type is)?

Comment: @jon-skeet A huge effort and not to mention a budget had been put in the research and implementation of all these new technologies, and it's for our good. I agree. But I won't believe that the source code posted in this question will by any means operate only on a select with joins. Can you make an estimate on how many database queries this source code will execute and on how many result sets it will iterate?

Comment: @Oguz: No, but a) I wouldn't use this code; b) I wouldn't estimate, I would measure.

Comment: Can you make `Business.Interactions` properly linked to the business so it functions as an `IQueryable` instead of an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @jon-skeet We need to give directions to make him use the correct code however. Otherwise, we can't stop people from upvoting a comment like the first one (at 15 votes now).

Comment: Just to clarify that original comment I left and walked away from until now... I had originally intended it to be a quick fix to the problem since I had seen it as bad algorithms / LINQ->SQL conversions. I didn't mean it to be a blanket statement to *never* use an ORM like some people are interpreting it. Listen to what @JonSkeet and spender said above, but don't feel like you *always* have to use an ORM to do a complex task like in this one. Sometimes the SQL will triumph.